# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException db2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have a aplication with Hibernate + bd2 + Spring and when i execute a job, i have this error

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query

Comment: please add your code to the question.

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!